# Cannot produce and finalize blocks with 2 node peer

Tags: finality, chainspec, tutorials

I want to connect 2 nodes via custom chain specification via Internet IP public

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/

I. STEP 1: Create Aura and grandpa

--- NODE 01----

1. Create Aura-01:

```
    Secret phrase:       glory icon taste syrup such guard correct occur coyote frequent thing water
      Network ID:        substrate
      Secret seed:       0x070c94ef16c1a629ddf6b9d1416fa2665e7d5f01bd2113e61a78c53f6e5cda87
      Public key (hex):  0x0adf0e0405dbc259257c2eb6700d00849a94edf496872dbea5547d236a9aff00
      Account ID:        0x0adf0e0405dbc259257c2eb6700d00849a94edf496872dbea5547d236a9aff00
      Public key (SS58): 5CJxbavev61VDuLbyMErtE7PvjA8osHhDkv3gKttHsSZFMdJ
      SS58 Address:      5CJxbavev61VDuLbyMErtE7PvjA8osHhDkv3gKttHsSZFMdJ
```

2. Create Grandpa-01

```
    Secret phrase:       glory icon taste syrup such guard correct occur coyote frequent thing water
      Network ID:        substrate
      Secret seed:       0x070c94ef16c1a629ddf6b9d1416fa2665e7d5f01bd2113e61a78c53f6e5cda87
      Public key (hex):  0x8e34ea1bd11bd532427f82daae6aa3a855fdc948136753905a74796a5b7146c8
      Account ID:        0x8e34ea1bd11bd532427f82daae6aa3a855fdc948136753905a74796a5b7146c8
      Public key (SS58): 5FHANk2EkM6sTeGnkZ2HaRCj356NVWg4DSJag4gsz6Jupazt
      SS58 Address:      5FHANk2EkM6sTeGnkZ2HaRCj356NVWg4DSJag4gsz6Jupazt
```

---NODE 02-------------------

3. Create Aura-02:

```
    Secret phrase:       praise scout author learn bounce funny pulp caution young collect whip limb
      Network ID:        substrate
      Secret seed:       0x16df58dcb530ece94270a6154c7d8ad1b3d4aebe69ce55ed2cfe620f6e357a1d
      Public key (hex):  0x16134c09a7818a590ebc5f9b336c22fe3d23e88e6449edbb996116449430be01
      Account ID:        0x16134c09a7818a590ebc5f9b336c22fe3d23e88e6449edbb996116449430be01
      Public key (SS58): 5CZeeFRsRSUweVkqZR3hDTN9khk3U3oa4rjaFg2S96WPpRhd
      SS58 Address:      5CZeeFRsRSUweVkqZR3hDTN9khk3U3oa4rjaFg2S96WPpRhd
```

4. Create Grandpa-02:

```
    Secret phrase:       praise scout author learn bounce funny pulp caution young collect whip limb
      Network ID:        substrate
      Secret seed:       0x16df58dcb530ece94270a6154c7d8ad1b3d4aebe69ce55ed2cfe620f6e357a1d
      Public key (hex):  0x3612c18b4ae0e6b7e5b5bd79b5353cc20af70ba1302fe638884114ee0b9a7452
      Account ID:        0x3612c18b4ae0e6b7e5b5bd79b5353cc20af70ba1302fe638884114ee0b9a7452
      Public key (SS58): 5DHc1oW2bBAfu46v5mxNu97iWohvEvsdT2TyaBirXuQzC18F
      SS58 Address:      5DHc1oW2bBAfu46v5mxNu97iWohvEvsdT2TyaBirXuQzC18F
```

II. STEP 2: Node 01 Export the local chain specification to a file named customSpec.json

```
    ./target/release/node-template build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json
```

III. STEP 3: Node-01 Add Aura and Grandpa both of node into customSpec.json

IV. Convert customSpec to RAW

```
    ./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json
```

V.Share customSpecRAW file to node-02

[Link RAW file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADk2rRhoubjmCu0jzwsbiCCj6CrImsys/view?usp=sharing)

VI.NODE-01 Run:

```
    ./target/release/node-template \
    --base-path /tmp/node01 \
    --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
    --port 30333 \
    --ws-port 9945 \
    --rpc-port 9933 \
    --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
    --validator \
    --rpc-methods Unsafe \
    --name MyNode01
```

VII.NODE-01 Add key to Keystore with password 123456

```
./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Sr25519 \
--suri '0x070c94ef16c1a629ddf6b9d1416fa2665e7d5f01bd2113e61a78c53f6e5cda87' \
--password-interactive \
--key-type aura


./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Ed25519 \
--suri '0x070c94ef16c1a629ddf6b9d1416fa2665e7d5f01bd2113e61a78c53f6e5cda87' \
--password-interactive \
--key-type gran
```

VIII. NODE-01 verify key

```
ls /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore
```

IX.NODE-02 run:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9946 \
--rpc-port 9934 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name MyNode02 \
--bootnodes /ip4/171.245.164.166/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBNTdqMcbcE3gqNWtvKWZWsFnHaehtMtbiq3kVeUk3JSE \
--password-interactive
```

X.NODE-02 Add key to keystore with password 123456

```
./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Sr25519 \
--suri '0x16df58dcb530ece94270a6154c7d8ad1b3d4aebe69ce55ed2cfe620f6e357a1d' \
--password-interactive \
--key-type aura


./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--scheme Ed25519 \
--suri '0x16df58dcb530ece94270a6154c7d8ad1b3d4aebe69ce55ed2cfe620f6e357a1d' \
--password-interactive \
--key-type gran
```

XI. NODE-02 verify key store

```
ls /tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/keystore
```

Result is both nodes can peer without producing and finalizing blocks.
[image]

Also same problem with 3 nodes.
Can anyone help me this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Updated to https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/ - have you tried with instructions here?

Comment: I tried over ten times but same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem is substrate. Substrate version v9.20 has problem, so can not peer-id or product block or finalize block.

After I upgrade to v9.24, this issuse was gone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Steps in configuring local_testnet (private network)

1. Create bootnode keys:

```
# botnode aura
$ subkey generate --scheme sr25519
Secret phrase:       tackle memory pepper lake seed afford since state power label brick copy
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0x81d794359885bb885c357dbf1bf75aff0f6744d532340d9418557ee43c8642ee
  Public key (hex):  0x34edf846c91511ca2b33d201a82b4a801b177feb6583dd56b8b589226441b272
  Account ID:        0x34edf846c91511ca2b33d201a82b4a801b177feb6583dd56b8b589226441b272
  Public key (SS58): 5DG73DMGcRCdJD55tnMuzAfb9MkwKsgpW5ft7DBpnUxpW3Wg
  SS58 Address:      5DG73DMGcRCdJD55tnMuzAfb9MkwKsgpW5ft7DBpnUxpW3Wg

# botnode gran
$ subkey inspect --scheme ed25519 "tackle memory pepper lake seed afford since state power label brick copy"
Secret phrase:       tackle memory pepper lake seed afford since state power label brick copy
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0x81d794359885bb885c357dbf1bf75aff0f6744d532340d9418557ee43c8642ee
  Public key (hex):  0x468d07453610d714e22a33c03b3004dc3b8efb146ec1f2200ae8d68102f0ffe7
  Account ID:        0x468d07453610d714e22a33c03b3004dc3b8efb146ec1f2200ae8d68102f0ffe7
  Public key (SS58): 5DfD6wftdWs3VqsajyEZMZjsBLk9jTZV5PfihZ3GFCe8YCu7
  SS58 Address:      5DfD6wftdWs3VqsajyEZMZjsBLk9jTZV5PfihZ3GFCe8YCu7
```

2. Create node2 keys:

```
# node2 aura
$ subkey generate --scheme sr25519
Secret phrase:       clump distance vast head photo mass run mosquito chicken wash tattoo escape
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0xca425677c85da882ecec057b47af3ab282253b9d27ed35f9835bc2b794c3d348
  Public key (hex):  0xd4aa883727fb3c36507dbba6b45fed749c3d2abbf7411b52461445b0a3403e15
  Account ID:        0xd4aa883727fb3c36507dbba6b45fed749c3d2abbf7411b52461445b0a3403e15
  Public key (SS58): 5GsYff9q6wdjt2hXcWyt6W9K7mctwDWpT8QJguMj2svuvnU9
  SS58 Address:      5GsYff9q6wdjt2hXcWyt6W9K7mctwDWpT8QJguMj2svuvnU9

# node2 gran
$ subkey inspect --scheme ed25519 "clump distance vast head photo mass run mosquito chicken wash tattoo escape"
Secret phrase:       clump distance vast head photo mass run mosquito chicken wash tattoo escape
  Network ID:        substrate
  Secret seed:       0xca425677c85da882ecec057b47af3ab282253b9d27ed35f9835bc2b794c3d348
  Public key (hex):  0xa6c1df110420b87d24aa56d9887c6e8a346f8bf9016e685d6f1c8d7cb8085cf1
  Account ID:        0xa6c1df110420b87d24aa56d9887c6e8a346f8bf9016e685d6f1c8d7cb8085cf1
  Public key (SS58): 5FqMQ2bbE3uFmrbiAz4J3Cr3QdEq8NL48BgkVQZYbxFhnf5k
  SS58 Address:      5FqMQ2bbE3uFmrbiAz4J3Cr3QdEq8NL48BgkVQZYbxFhnf5k
```

3. Authorized the aura and gran addresses for both nodes in the CustomSpec.json file.

```
#...
      "aura": {
        "authorities": [
          "5DG73DMGcRCdJD55tnMuzAfb9MkwKsgpW5ft7DBpnUxpW3Wg",
          "5GsYff9q6wdjt2hXcWyt6W9K7mctwDWpT8QJguMj2svuvnU9"
        ]
      },
      "grandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5DfD6wftdWs3VqsajyEZMZjsBLk9jTZV5PfihZ3GFCe8YCu7",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5FqMQ2bbE3uFmrbiAz4J3Cr3QdEq8NL48BgkVQZYbxFhnf5k",
            1
          ]
        ]
      },
      "balances": {
        "balances": [
          [
            "5DG73DMGcRCdJD55tnMuzAfb9MkwKsgpW5ft7DBpnUxpW3Wg",
            100000000000000000000000
          ]
        ]
      },
      "transactionPayment": null,
      "sudo": {
        "key": "5DG73DMGcRCdJD55tnMuzAfb9MkwKsgpW5ft7DBpnUxpW3Wg"
      }
#...
```

4. Create a bootnode (node01) shell script command:

```
# run-bootnode.sh
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-cors all \
--ws-external \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name MyNode01
```

4. Create a node2 (node02) shell script command (the node id of the bootnode may change from time to time, please take note of that carefully):

```
# run-node2.sh
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9934 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-cors all \
--ws-external \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name MyNode02 \
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWAk2PkrAqmEaqGtGc8ieUARYWmTyJkimpndd1F1f3ZJWZ \
```

5. Purge all db and keystore.  Take note that if you restart your computer, your keystore also will be deleted.

```
$ ./target/release/node-template purge-chain --base-path /tmp/node01 
$ rm -rf /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore
$ ./target/release/node-template purge-chain --base-path /tmp/node02
$ rm -rf /tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/keystore
```

6. Now run the two nodes i different terminal.

```
$ ./run-bootnode.sh
```

```
$ ./run-node2.sh
```

7. Register the keys of the bootnode.
   [image: bootnode/aura]
   [image: bootnode/gran]
8. Register the keys of node2.  Make sure your polkadotJS is really connected to node2, if not this will not work.
   [image: node2/aura]
   [image: node2/grand]
9. Check the keystore for each node

```
$ ls /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore
617572611c98e60ea5fb1dfd0f72996afd2e35294ac4f33dfd4937489c43c65222e06347
6772616ea77e7345133bd15486b7745bade1eed84d8bde1abfc5ea7199411a1fc865786e

$ ls //tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/keystore
61757261540f2298562a57b3348968793b2e6a5d623232a7d353356d621456f49ebe8902
6772616ea8b2e3955493c2d2608ce6013da726b15982710f1b045fff97e07fe0e3f753b4
```

9. Re-run the node.  Thats it.

Comment: i have tried ur approach, but still i can see only peer logs but, not the new blocks producing and finalizing,

can you please let me know, if u have any resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Grandpa works with atleast 3 nodes because its using voting system to finalize blocks

Comment: It would help to add reference to the docs for this for people to learn :)

Comment: I run 3 nodes, still same errors

Comment: Grandpa requires a 2f+1 non-faulty node (i.e., a two-thirds majority) to finalise blocks. So it depends on how many grandpa authorities you have configured & what is their weightage, it can't be absolute 3 nodes. More info here: https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/consensus/#default-consensus-models

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "key insert".  It does not work!  Go to polkadot.js and use RPC Calls/Authors/Insert Keys.

Make sure to connect to the appropriate node while inserting their keys.

Make sure to purge also, you might have inserted invalid keys in there.

Comment: I try to purge then use RPC Calls/Authors/Insert Keys.
-Keytype:Text = aura
-suri: Text = glory icon taste syrup such guard correct occur coyote frequent thing water
-publicKey = 0x0adf0e0405dbc259257c2eb6700d00849a94edf496872dbea5547d236a9aff00
(publicKey is publicKey hex, right?)

-Keytype:Text = gran
-suri: Text = glory icon taste syrup such guard correct occur coyote frequent thing water
-publicKey = 0x8e34ea1bd11bd532427f82daae6aa3a855fdc948136753905a74796a5b7146c8

still same issue.

Comment: When I restart node-1 then have new error.

GRANDPA voter error: could not sign outgoing message: Failed to sign GRANDPA vote for round 1 targetting 0x9b4ee454930c1cf0f52d592136a35c8c20ee15caa177b06f8e8502423fe5d004    
2022-06-29 14:47:02 Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.    
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))

Comment: A. 1. You must have two nodes to be able to run aura-gran consensus, 2. generate aura: subkey generate --scheme sr25519, generate gran: subkey inspect --scheme ed25519 <use-same-mnemonics-in-aura>, 3. Make sure that when you encode the keys you use the correct public hex for aura and gran

Comment: B. 1. For the second node, make sure to connect to the second node before your provide the aura and gran keys, 2. Follow the process of letter A.

Comment: You can check /tmp/node01/local_testnet/keystore for node01, after you put the keys.

Comment: You can check /tmp/node02/local_testnet/keystore, after you put the keys of the second node.  There should only be 2 keys in there, one for aura and one for gran

Comment: By the way, I forgot, make sure you authorized these validator addresses in your customSpecRaw.json file.

Comment: I check step by step A, B, keystore node01, node02. It's fine

Comment: About authorized these validator addresses. How to authorized? I tried 2 way: 1- use the command "ls /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore" 2-use the RPC/sudo/sudo access/nodeAuthorization/addWellKnownNode. How to find PeerId node (hex) and Owner: AccountId32 of current node?

Comment: Could I connect to you via IM message? To easy check my step by step, maybe there is mistake when I do.

Comment: Sure you can, just let me know when.

Comment: My telegram: https://t.me/oscardollars